# Select box not updating when model is changed programmatically

Tags: angularjs, jquery-mobile, drop-down-menu, jquery-mobile-popup

I have a select box in a popup that i assign an initial value without any problems. However, I want to change the select boxes value when I open the popup the issue is that although it "ticks" the changed value it does not show it in the select box unless I open and close the popup again. Any solutions to making the select box update so that when I open the pop up for the first time the value assigned is showing?

Note: in production i am using angularJs to populate the select box and jqmobile to render it.

Here is the fiddle and the code: https://jsfiddle.net/AKMorris/ufcasngf/6/

```
  <button ng-click="openPopup()">open popup</button>
  <div data-role="popup" id="mypopup" data-overlay-theme="d" data-theme="none">
    <select id="fcComparator" 
            ng-model="ccEditorFcComparator"
            ng-options="fcEnumComp for fcEnumComp in ccEditorDefaultComparators"
            >
    </select>
  </div>
```

the js:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.ccEditorDefaultComparators = ["=","!="];
    $scope.ccEditorFcComparator = "!=";

  $scope.openPopup = function()
  {
    $('#mypopup').popup();
    $('#mypopup').popup('open', { y: 0 });

    console.log("should switch to = now");
        $scope.ccEditorFcComparator = "=";

        //this makes it work the second time you open the popup
    $('#fcComparator').selectmenu('refresh');
  }
});
```

Comment: by inspecting the `select` i see both options having in markup 'selected="selected"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you change the value of the select using the jQuery function (`.option()`) for `selectmenu`, it updates the select box properly.

**Ng-repeat solution:**

[JSFiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/dnyg2qy8/9/)

**Ng-options Solution:**

[JSFiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/dnyg2qy8/8/)

**NOTE:** You need to separetely assign the ng-model variable also for this fix to work.

**JS:**

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.ccEditorDefaultComparators = ["=","!="];
    $scope.ccEditorFcComparator = "!=";
  
  $scope.openPopup = function()
  {
    $('#fcComparator').selectmenu('refresh');
    $('#mypopup').popup();
    $('#mypopup').popup('open', { y: 0 });
    console.log("should switch to = now");
        $('#fcComparator').val("=");
        $scope.ccEditorFcComparator = "=";
        //this makes it work the second time you open the popup
    $('#fcComparator').selectmenu('refresh');
  }
});
```

**References:**

1. [jQuery Select Menu Documentation](http://api.jqueryui.com/selectmenu/#method-instance)

Comment: Your fiddle doesn't work, the popup shows "!=" not "="

Comment: @AKMorris Updated my answer, please check :)

Comment: Although it is an answer it is still useless to me. I need to use angularJs ng-options (as per my original code) to populate the select box this means I cannot hard code <option> tags like you have.

Comment: @AKMorris Updated my answer!

Comment: Excellent, it is working now. Doesn't feel great having to assign the value twice but it is all I have to work with for now.

Comment: @AKMorris You're welcome ....might I suggest going for an angular popup plugin instead.....because you are using a jQuery angular does not detect the variable change, but this fix will help you out surely

Answer (score 0):

Would it be an option to just create another controller for the popup and set the selected option there?

HTML

```
<div data-ng-app='myApp' data-ng-controller='myCtrl'>

  <button id="popup-btn" ng-click="openPopup()">open popup</button>

  <div data-role="popup" id="mypopup" data-overlay-theme="d" data-theme="none" ng-controller="myPopup">
    <select id="fcComparator" 
       ng-model="ccEditorFcComparator"
       ng-options="fcEnumComp for fcEnumComp in ccEditorDefaultComparators">
    </select>
  </div>

</div>
```

Javascript

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope, $timeout) {
  $scope.openPopup = function()  {
    $('#mypopup').popup();
    $('#mypopup').popup('open', { y: 0 });
  }
});

app.controller('myPopup', function($scope, $timeout) {
    $scope.ccEditorDefaultComparators = ["=","!="];
    $scope.ccEditorFcComparator = "=";
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/wjjafupf/

Comment: I need the model to be set to the initial condition ($scope.ccEditorFcComparator = "!=";) and then on popup it sets to "=".

Comment: Would this solution work using a factory or service to communicate/transfer the initial ccEditorFcComparator value of "!=" from the 'myCtrl' controller to the second 'myPopup' controller? Basically, I need to determine the value of the popup select box based on the initial value set in 'myCtrl' e.g. if initial value is "!=" then set the popup to "=".